# "Unknown escape sequence" warning for regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm getting following warnings as a result my regex. Here's the line:

```
#define REGEX_FEILD_USERNAME @"[/\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+\z/]"
```

Warnings

```
unknown escape sequence \z
unknown escape sequence \A
unknown escape sequence \$
unknown escape sequence \^
```

How to solve this?

Comment: you  need to escape \ one more time. It seems like your regex is wrong.

Comment: What do you want to match? Your regex currently doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I want to validate the user name. It should be alpha numeric and some other special characters like a`comes in other languages like french ....

Comment: @sajaz: If it is username, restrict it to something familiar, like [A-Za-z0-9_-]. For display name, let the user enter whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that string will be seen by the compiler you need to escape the `\` characters as they have meaning within string literals:

```
#define REGEX_FEILD_USERNAME @"[/\\A[^0-9`!@#\\$%\\^&*+_=]+\\z/]"
```